# How to get object collection from another collection?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, ria, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have a collection defined as:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> Employees;
```

Entity Employee has property Person. 
I have loaded Employees from Ria service including Person with eager-loading.
Now I want to get the collection of Person from Employees, something like

```
IEnumerable<Person> People = Employees.Person;
```

How to use Linq to get all Person? any other solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it should be as easy as (assuming `Person` isn't another collection):

```
var persons = Employees.Select(e => e.Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
IEnumerable<Employee> collection = ...;
IEnumerable<Person> persons = collection.Select(x => x.Person);
```